# validation to a radio List in struts 2

Tags: list, validation, radio-button, struts2

I have a surveying application were each question in an iterated list needs to have at least one of its optional answered selected. 
I want to validate using struts 2 , that each question has been answered.
many thanks,
Mbayader

Answer (score 1):

One ways to accomplish on your requirement is by extending the class struts2 ActionSupport class. Then you should override the super validate() method to your business requirement in which you have mentioned in your question.

Comment: i wanted to validate the radio by using the validation.xml file, would it be possible to do so.