# How to validate radio buttons in Struts2

Tags: tomcat, struts2

I have a radio button in a form in a Struts2 application. I can validate textbox fields, but I cannot do it for a radio button (one must be checked) and for a checkboxlist (at least one must be checked).

I have followed some pages telling about the topic but none of the solutions works.

Finally I have this in the XML file:

```
<field name="sexo">
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">
        <param name="trim">true</param>
        <message>*</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Added:**

This is the action class: (does it matter if no validation related code exists?)

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package agenda;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;

/**
 *
 * @author Jaime
 */
public class ProfileAction {

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String nombres;
    private String apellidopaterno;
    private String apellidomaterno;
    private String fechanacimiento;
    private String direccion;
    private String comuna;
    private String telefonofijo;
    private String telefonomovil;
    private String email;
    private String sexo;
    private String[] subscripcion;

    public ProfileAction() {
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return @throws Exception
     */
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String usuario = (String) session.getAttribute("id");
        if (usuario != null && !usuario.equals("") && !usuario.equals("0")) {
            return "success";
        } else {
            return "error";
        }
    }

    /**
     * Muestra el formulario de registro de cliente
     *
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public String register() throws Exception {
        return "success";
    }

    /**
     * @return the username
     */
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    /**
     * @param username the username to set
     */
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    /**
     * @return the password
     */
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    /**
     * @param password the password to set
     */
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    /**
     * @return the nombres
     */
    public String getNombres() {
        return nombres;
    }

    /**
     * @param nombres the nombres to set
     */
    public void setNombres(String nombres) {
        this.nombres = nombres;
    }

    /**
     * @return the apellidopaterno
     */
    public String getApellidopaterno() {
        return apellidopaterno;
    }

    /**
     * @param apellidopaterno the apellidopaterno to set
     */
    public void setApellidopaterno(String apellidopaterno) {
        this.apellidopaterno = apellidopaterno;
    }

    /**
     * @return the apellidomaterno
     */
    public String getApellidomaterno() {
        return apellidomaterno;
    }

    /**
     * @param apellidomaterno the apellidomaterno to set
     */
    public void setApellidomaterno(String apellidomaterno) {
        this.apellidomaterno = apellidomaterno;
    }

    /**
     * @return the fechanacimiento
     */
    public String getFechanacimiento() {
        return fechanacimiento;
    }

    /**
     * @param fechanacimiento the fechanacimiento to set
     */
    public void setFechanacimiento(String fechanacimiento) {
        this.fechanacimiento = fechanacimiento;
    }

    /**
     * @return the direccion
     */
    public String getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
    }

    /**
     * @param direccion the direccion to set
     */
    public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }

    /**
     * @return the comuna
     */
    public String getComuna() {
        return comuna;
    }

    /**
     * @param comuna the comuna to set
     */
    public void setComuna(String comuna) {
        this.comuna = comuna;
    }

    /**
     * @return the telefonofijo
     */
    public String getTelefonofijo() {
        return telefonofijo;
    }

    /**
     * @param telefonofijo the telefonofijo to set
     */
    public void setTelefonofijo(String telefonofijo) {
        this.telefonofijo = telefonofijo;
    }

    /**
     * @return the telefonomovil
     */
    public String getTelefonomovil() {
        return telefonomovil;
    }

    /**
     * @param telefonomovil the telefonomovil to set
     */
    public void setTelefonomovil(String telefonomovil) {
        this.telefonomovil = telefonomovil;
    }

    /**
     * @return the email
     */
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    /**
     * @param email the email to set
     */
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    /**
     * @return the sexo
     */
    public String getSexo() {
        return sexo;
    }

    /**
     * @param sexo the sexo to set
     */
    public void setSexo(String sexo) {
        this.sexo = sexo;
    }

    /**
     * @return the subscripcion
     */
    public String[] getSubscripcion() {
        return subscripcion;
    }

    /**
     * @param subscripcion the subscripcion to set
     */
    public void setSubscripcion(String[] subscripcion) {
        this.subscripcion = subscripcion;
    }
}
```

This is the JSP file:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags" %>

<script src="js/jquery/jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery/jquery.selectbox-0.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="register">
    <ul><li><a href="#frm_registro"><span><s:text name="profile.register" /></span></a></li></ul>
    <div id="frm_registro">
        <s:div id="avisoError"><s:text name="profile.requiredtext" /></s:div>
        <s:form id="registro"
                action="proceso_registro" theme="css_xhtml" validate="true">
            <s:textfield name="username" key="profile.rut" labelposition="left" maxlength="50" />
            <s:password name="password" key="profile.password" labelposition="left" maxlength="50" />
            <s:textfield name="nombres" key="profile.nombres" labelposition="left" maxlength="80" size="40" />
            <s:textfield name="apellidopaterno" key="profile.apellidopaterno" labelposition="left" maxlength="80" size="40" />
            <s:textfield name="apellidomaterno" key="profile.apellidomaterno" labelposition="left" maxlength="80" size="40" />
            <s:textfield name="fechanacimiento" key="profile.fechanacimiento" labelposition="left" />
            <s:textfield name="direccion" key="profile.direccion" labelposition="left" maxlength="80" size="40" />
            <s:select name="comuna" key="profile.comuna" labelposition="left" list="#{'1':'Santiago', '2':'Huechuraba'}" headerValue="-= Seleccione Comuna =-  " headerKey="" />
            <s:textfield name="telefonofijo" key="profile.telefonofijo" labelposition="left" maxlength="30" size="30" />
            <s:textfield name="telefonomovil" key="profile.telefonomovil" labelposition="left" maxlength="30" size="30" />
            <s:textfield name="email" key="profile.email" labelposition="left" maxlength="30" size="30" />
            <s:radio name="sexo" key="profile.sexo" labelposition="left" list="#{'M':'Masculino', 'F':'Femenino'}" />
            <s:checkboxlist name="subscripcion" key="profile.subscripcion" labelposition="left" list="#{'T':'Teléfono', 'E':'E-mail', 'M':'Mensaje de Texto'}" value="T" />

            <s:submit id="boton_registro" align="left" cssClass="send" value="Registrarse" />
        </s:form>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $( "#register" ).tabs();
    $( "#boton_registro" ).button();
    $( "#registro_fechanacimiento" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy", 
        showOn: "both", 
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        buttonImage: "images/datepicker_icon.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: "<s:text name="AgendaPlus.choosedate" />"});
    $( "#registro_fechanacimiento" ).mask("99/99/9999");                                             
    $.mask.definitions['~']='[0-9kK]';
    $( "#registro_username" ).mask("99.999.999-~");
    $( "#registro_comuna" ).selectbox({
        effect: "fade"
    });    
    $( "#registro_telefonofijo" ).mask("(99) 9999 9999");                                             
    $( "#registro_telefonomovil" ).mask("(09) 9999 9999");                                             
</script>
```

This is part of the configuration XML file:

```
    <action name="registro" class="agenda.ProfileAction" method="register">
        <result name="success" type="tiles">/register.tiles</result>
        <result name="input" type="tiles">/register.tiles</result>
    </action>        

    <action name="proceso_registro" class="agenda.ProfileAction" method="register">
        <interceptor-ref name="profiling">
            <param name="profilingKey">profilingKey</param>
        </interceptor-ref>            
        <interceptor-ref name="jsonValidationWorkflowStack"/>            
        <result name="success" type="tiles">/register.success.tiles</result>
        <result name="input" type="tiles">/register.tiles</result>
    </action>
```

The "registro" action is the entry point (the form), as this URL shows: http://domain.cl:8080/AgendaPlus/registro

And finally, this is the whole validation file (ProfileAction-validation.xml)

```
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "-//Apache Struts//XWork Validator 1.0.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-1.0.3.dtd">
<validators>
    <field name="username">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <param name="trim">true</param>
            <message>Requerido</message>
        </field-validator>
        <field-validator type="rutValidator">
            <param name="trim">true</param>
            <message key="errors.short_invalid" />
        </field-validator>
    </field>
    <field name="password">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <param name="trim">true</param>
            <message>*</message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>    
    <field name="nombres">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <param name="trim">true</param>
            <message>*</message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>
    <field name="apellidopaterno">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <param name="trim">true</param>
            <message>*</message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>
    <field name="fechanacimiento">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <param name="trim">true</param>
            <message>*</message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>    
    <field name="comuna">
        <field-validator type="int">
            <param name="min">1</param>
            <message>*</message>
        </field-validator>        
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <param name="trim">true</param>
            <message>*</message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>    
    <field name="telefonofijo">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <param name="trim">true</param>
            <message>*</message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>    
    <field name="telefonomovil">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <param name="trim">true</param>
            <message>*</message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>    
    <field name="email">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <param name="trim">true</param>
            <message>*</message>
        </field-validator>
        <field-validator type="email">
            <param name="trim">true</param>
            <message key="errors.short_invalid" />
        </field-validator>        
    </field>    
    <field name="sexo">
        <field-validator type="required">
            <param name="trim">true</param>
            <message>*</message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>    
    <field name="subscripcion">
        <field-validator type="fieldexpression">
            <param name="expression"><![CDATA[#subscripcion.size() > 0]]></param>
            <message>al menos uno</message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>    
</validators>
```

As you see, that validation.xml file is different from most xml present in Struts2 tutorials, even when I am using Struts2 too. But this XML file works at least for all field but for my custom validator, the radio buttons and the checkbox list. When using validation.xml from other tutorials, does not work anything.

Best regards,

Thanks
Jaime

Comment: POSSIBLE DUPLICATE OF http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242590/validation-to-a-radio-list-in-struts-2

Comment: Yes... it is duplicated, however I have already read the solution there, I followed the example, but it did not work. It does not validate anything, while the way I have implemented, validates all but the radio buttons and checkboxes. The link with a tutorial pointed in the message link you posted uses a very distinct XML syntax for the validator.xml file.

Comment: @jstuardo: Could your post your action and JSP page.

Comment: I have added the codes to the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `required` validator instead of `requiredstring`. The `required` validator checks if the specified field is not null.

```
<field name="sexo">
    <field-validator type="required">
        <param name="trim">true</param>
        <message>*</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>
```

And for "at least one" condition you can use [`fieldexpression`](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/fieldexpression-validator.html) validator.

**Update**

Since your `subscripcion` is array you need to use `length` variable not `size` method, and w/o `#` in front of it.

```
<field name="subscripcion">
    <field-validator type="fieldexpression">
        <param name="expression"><![CDATA[subscripcion.length > 0]]></param>
        <message>al menos uno</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>
```

Comment: Hello.. for radio, it does not work either.... I have this defined: <s:radio name="sexo" key="profile.sexo" labelposition="left" list="#{'M':'Masculino', 'F':'Femenino'}" />. For checkboxlist, I have  this expression: <![CDATA[#subscripcion.size() > 0]]> where #subscripcion is defined as <s:checkboxlist name="subscripcion" key="profile.subscripcion" labelposition="left" list="#{'T':'Teléfono', 'E':'E-mail', 'M':'Mensaje de Texto'}" value="T" /> and it does not work.

Comment: @jstuardo: Updated my answer. And for you case `requiredstring` should work for radio button also.